# Usar valor de diccionario para obtener llave

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo este código donde debo traducir números a letras, basado en un teclado de teléfono.

```
def funcion(string):
cambio = ''
    teclado = {'a': '21', 'b': '22', 'c': '23', 'd': '31', 'e': '32', 'f': '33', 'g': '41', 'h': '42', 'i': '43',
              'j': '51', 'k': '52', 'l': '53', 'm': '61', 'n': '62', 'o': '63','p': '71', 'q': '72', 'r': '73', 's': '74',
              't': '81', 'u': '82', 'v': '83', 'w': '91', 'x': '92', 'y': '93', 'z': '94', ' ':'*'}
    for letra in string:
        cambio += teclado[letra] + ' '
    return cambio
```

El código anterior me funciona para pasar de letras a números. Hay forma de invertir el proceso para que pase números a letras, sin modificar el diccionario?

Comment: `[key for key,val in teclado.items() if val==un_numero ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si hay forma, podrías recorrer el diccionario y buscar la llave que tiene "X" valor

El método `items()` devuelve una tupla de llave, valor de un diccionario, si utilizamos el código siguiente puedes ver que para cada elemento de `teclado` imprime su llave y su valor

```
teclado = {'a': '21', 'b': '22', 'c': '23', 'd': '31', 'e': '32', 'f': '33', 'g': '41', 'h': '42', 'i': '43',
              'j': '51', 'k': '52', 'l': '53', 'm': '61', 'n': '62', 'o': '63','p': '71', 'q': '72', 'r': '73', 's': '74',
              't': '81', 'u': '82', 'v': '83', 'w': '91', 'x': '92', 'y': '93', 'z': '94', ' ':'*'}
for k, v in teclado.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
a 21
b 22
c 23
d 31
e 32
f 33
g 41
h 42
i 43
j 51
k 52
l 53
m 61
n 62
o 63
p 71
q 72
r 73
s 74
t 81
u 82
v 83
w 91
x 92
y 93
z 94
  *
```

Por lo que podrías buscar el valor de `v` que sea igual a "X" número que deseas encontrar y regresar el valor de `k` que vendría siendo la llave

```
x = '41'
for k, v in teclado.items():
    if(v==x):
        print(k)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
g
```

Utilizando el mismo principio, podemos crear una comprensión de diccionario y reducir el código a una sola línea. Por ejemplo aquí buscamos que `v` sea igual a '41'.

```
print([k for k, v in teclado.items() if v == '41'])
```

Esto devuelve

```
['g']
```

Comment: Me sirvió a la perfección, muchas gracias!